# Cron.php return Forbidden error

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to set up a schedule feed using /cron.php, but I keep receiving a 403 forbidden message.  I have Magento 1.9, I am not a developer so have minimum knowledge, and I use 123-reg cpannel.

I have seen that code needs to be put in a .zip file, but not sure where I find this.  Can someone please talk me through how I make this work.  Also been told that I can put some code in the command file but cannot find that either, have found the shell file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

set up `cron.sh` file in cron , you can use below command for that

```
 * * * * *   sh  /yourmagentoroot/cron.php
```

this way you can set up the cron

Answer (score 0):

You need to comment below lines in .htaccess file:

```
<Files cron.php>
        #Order allow,deny
                #Deny from all
    </Files>
```

Now you can access cron.php.